# Mutex is not held in this async block

Tags: mutex, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, kotlin-flow

I'm doing the Advanced coroutines with Kotlin flow and LiveData code lab and encountered this function in `CacheOnSuccess.kt`.

There is a comment that says "// Note: mutex is not held in this async block". What does this mean exactly? Why wouldn't the mutex be held in the async block? And what is the significance of that?

```
    suspend fun getOrAwait(): T {
        return supervisorScope {
            // This function is thread-safe _iff_ deferred is @Volatile and all reads and writes
            // hold the mutex.

            // only allow one coroutine to try running block at a time by using a coroutine-base
            // Mutex
            val currentDeferred = mutex.withLock {
                deferred?.let { return@withLock it }

                async {
                    // Note: mutex is not held in this async block
                    block()
                }.also {
                    // Note: mutex is held here
                    deferred = it
                }
            }

            // await the result, with our custom error handling
            currentDeferred.safeAwait()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to `withLock` implementation, mutex is held on the just stack-frame, which means, after `withLock` execution the mutex is released, but code inside async *may* not execute right in that frame (maybe in another thread according to current Dispatchers), so probably when the block of async get executed, `withLock` call could have already returned, as for the `also` call, it is marked as `inline`, so it is executed in the current frame, right before `withLock` returned

Answer (score 1):

The mutex is held by at most one coroutine at any time. `async` launches a coroutine which doesn't attempt to acquire the mutex. The significance of that is the same as for any other mutex -- the code inside the `async` block isn't guarded by the mutex, so it must not touch the state that is required to be guarded by it.